# Mock only one function from module but leave rest with original functionality

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I only want to mock a single function (named export) from a module but leave the rest of the module functions intact.

Using `jest.mock('package-name')` makes all exported functions mocks, which I don't want.

I tried spreading the named exports back into the mock object...

```
import * as utils from './utilities.js';

jest.mock(utils, () => ({
  ...utils
  speak: jest.fn(),
}));
```

but got this error:

> The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.

Comment: For those that follow, `jest.mock()` actually gets [hoisted](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) like variables. As a result, they're called before the imports.

Answer (score 311):

The highlight of this answer is **jest.requireActual()**, this is a very useful utility that says to jest that "Hey keep every original functionalities intact and import them".

```
jest.mock('./utilities.js', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('./utilities.js'),
  speak: jest.fn(),
}));
```

Let's take another common scenario, you're using enzyme ShallowWrapper and it doesn't goes well with useContext() hook, so what're you gonna do? While i'm sure there are multiple ways, but this is the one I like:

```
import React from "react";

jest.mock("react", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react"), // import and retain the original functionalities
  useContext: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({foo: 'bar'}) // overwrite useContext
}))
```

The perk of doing it this way is that you can still use
`import React, { useContext } from "react"` in your original code without worrying about converting them into **React.useContext()** as you would if you're using **jest.spyOn(React, 'useContext')**

Comment: This worked for me. spyOn was useless in my case, as the method is not called in my test file.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue when trying to mock a single export function from a module inside node_modules

Comment: This does not work anymore in Jest 27: `Spread types may only be created from object types`.

Comment: @ypicard you have to store `jest.requireActual('./myModule')` in a variable first and then you can use the spread operator on the variable. https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename

Comment: This didn't work for me when using an index file to store many components without a default export. I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined`

Comment: It does not work for me. ```jest.mock``` and ```jest.requireActual``` works but when also try to mock one of the functions, my code keeps calling the original implementation

Comment: I was also getting a `Spread types may only be created from object types` error. I fixed it by casting to Module type like this: `...jest.requireActual('./modules/module') as Module`. For this, I added this import: `import Module from 'module';`

Comment: Thank you. Thank you so much. I've been struggling with mocking `react-i18next` and its `useTranslation` method, and it was giving me nightmares with `initReactI18next` being undefined module. With this, it finally worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: What if `useContext` is invoked multiple times and I wish to use `mockReturnValueOnce` to determine the return value in each case? How can I reference the useContext mock? Trying to declare it as a variable outside the mock causes an error (" The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables")

Comment: @ypicard, you also can do "...(jest.requireActual('react') as any)"

Comment: Started using this approach but can't seem to get it to work. I don't seem to be able to reference to mocked function in order to determine if it has been called. Similar to @csvan problem.

Comment: @BenGooding I found that if you import as usual from your index file but mock the full path to the module you want to mock it works well.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
`import { hook1, hook2 } from '../../../../../hooks'`

`jest.mock('../../../../../hooks/hook2')`

Comment: I'm having the same issue as @KubaK. My code keeps calling the original instead of the mock given in the factory.

Comment: @Popsicle Same with me my code keeps calling the original variable, instead of mocked one.

Comment: You can find more info about this approach on this article, which worked for me: https://dev.to/rafaf/mock-imported-modules-in-jest-26ng

Comment: Can someone help? This doesn't seem to work anymore in 2023

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, but the one using Proxy as suggested by @Rico Kahler below seems to do the job.

Answer (score 67):

The most straightforward way is to use `jest.spyOn` and then `.mockImplementation()`. This will allow all other functions in the module to continue working how they're defined.

For packages:

```
import axios from 'axios';

jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');
axios.get.mockImplementation(() => { /* do thing */ });
```

For modules with named exports:

```
import * as utils from './utilities.js';

jest.spyOn(utils, 'speak');
utils.speak.mockImplementation(() => { /* do thing */ });
```

Docs here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: This works if the function is called in my test file. But if the function is called/imported in another file it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: I consider this more elegant solution than require spread syntax. Moreover, you can assign spied function during `spyOn` call itself, like:
`const speakSpy = jest.spyOn(utils, "speak");`
and call it later:
`speakSpy.mockImplementation(() => { /* stuff */ });`

Comment: @tannerburton It works for functions imported in other files, when combined with `jest.mock()`, see example here: https://medium.com/trabe/mocking-different-values-for-the-same-module-using-jest-a7b8d358d78b

Answer (score 17):

`jest.requireActual` inside of `jest.mock` seems like the way to go, however I needed to add a proxy instead of the object spread to prevent the type error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ...)` which can occur in certain import scenarios.

This is the final result:

```js
jest.mock('the-module-to-mock', () => {
  const actualModule = jest.requireActual('the-module-to-mock')

  return new Proxy(actualModule, {
    get: (target, property) => {
      switch (property) {
        // add cases for exports you want to mock
        // 
        case 'foo': {
          return jest.fn() // add `mockImplementation` etc
        }
        case 'bar': {
          return jest.fn()
        }
        // fallback to the original module
        default: {
          return target[property]
        }
      }
    },
  })
})
```

Comment: This is when the file creates arrow functions. They're treated at object properties not class functions I think, so don't get mocked the same way.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. 20 hours of debugging and desperation and it finally works.

Comment: This is not working anymore 2023

Comment: This is a golden solution ⭐️

Answer (score 9):

For me this worked:

```
const utils = require('./utilities.js');
...
jest.spyOn(utils, 'speak').mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());
```

Comment: Not if `speak()` isn't going to be directly called from the test suite! If the tests call a function that calls `speak()` itself, this arrangement fails!

Answer (score 7):

I took Rico Kahler's answer and created this general purpose function:

```js
function mockPartially(packageName: string, getMocks: (actualModule: any) => any) {
  jest.doMock(packageName, () => {
    const actualModule = jest.requireActual(packageName);
    const mocks = getMocks(actualModule);

    return new Proxy(actualModule, {
      get: (target, property) => {
        if (property in mocks) {
          return mocks[property];
        } else {
          return target[property];
        }
      },
    });
  });
}
```

and you use it like this for example to mock lodash:

```js
mockPartially('lodash', (_actualLodash) => { //sometimes you need the actual module
   return {
      'isObject': () => true, //mock isObject
      'isArray': () => true // mock isArray
   }
});
```

Comment: This didnt work for me with es6 modules. Rico's answer worked.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest considering that the mock be setup so that it continues to call the original until the mocks are explicitly reset and setup with the desired mock behaviour just before the test that is interested in the function being mocked.

```
jest.mock("fs", () => {
  const originalFs = jest.requireActual("fs");

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalFs,
    // call original by default until specific tests as this avoids breaking
    // any imports that might perform a readFileSync when loading.
    readFileSync: jest.fn().mockImplementation((args) => originalFs.readFileSync(args)),
  };
});
```

To expand on why, most of the answers will work in most situations, however for any module from the core or an external library that is used by multiple other imports they can create a side effect.

When you use `jest.mock("<name>")`, it applies before imports are actually executed. Looking at https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules you can see the mock is after the import, but it still works as expected. However in https://jestjs.io/docs/bypassing-module-mocks the mock is created before which may not be obvious that it doesn't matter, even if afterwards jest hooks in early enough to apply the mock before what is in the import is processed.

This means that anything that is imported and tries to create a concrete instance of an object to set as a module property, will get the mocked instance rather than the original.

In some cases this might be what is intended, but more likely this will be surprising. By having the mock pass through to the original call initially, it allows for the function to used by other imports initial setup and can then be switched to use the needed mock implementation before testimg the function that calls it as well.

Obviously if you are mocking something you've written this is less important, more for when working with libraries and frameworks that can have dependencies and behaviour you might not be fully aware of.

In my case I got bitten by the context object in GitHub's `@actions/toolkit` looking to read a JSON file on load which only caused issues when the `GITHUB_EVENT_PATH` env var was set. https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/main/packages/github/src/context.ts